# confusing error on aws iam: "Syntax error in policy"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

So I'm trying to automate through python what I normally do on the aws:iam console.
This policy, validates as it is. As you see it here:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course the account ids are fake, but it **does validate**.

So feeding that same policy to this bit of code does not work:

```
def create(iam, name, desc, policy):

  response = iam.create_policy(
    PolicyName = name,
    Description = desc,
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy)
    )
```

That is taken from aws recommended way of doing this, ofc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-iam-create_policy.py.html

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
botocore.errorfactory.MalformedPolicyDocumentException: An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.
```

This is confusing me a bit as I do not see why it would not work this way when it works on the console. So after way too much time googling this, I simply cannot find anything that would help me, or I'm completely misguided here.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating an IAM policy with the policy you have posted and ran in to the same issue. It seems that the output from `json.dumps()` is the reason for the error.

You can do it this way though

```
import boto3


def create_iam_policy(iam, name, desc, policy):
    response = iam.create_policy(
        PolicyName = name,
        Description = desc,
        PolicyDocument= policy
      )
    return response

iam = boto3.client('iam')

my_managed_policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm",
                "arn:aws:iam::123465790123:role/account-adm"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

print(create_iam_policy(iam, 'test-policy', 'test desc', my_managed_policy))
```